# Как сделать свойства разного типа

Tags: django

Есть товар, него куча свойств, разные. Они  могут быть разных типов. У товара может быть разный набор свойств. Если идеи как реализовать?

Нужно учесть, что потом по ним будет поиск как по совпадению, так и по диапазону

Comment: Что мешает сделать модель  набором разных свойст, каждое из которых является не обязаетльным, а в качестве значения использовать строку. Я как понимаю у тебя же могут быть только примитивы, а ты их все можешь перегнать в строку

Comment: Есть модель "Свойства", Есть модель "Свойста товара". Сейчас она имеет несоклько полей для каждого типа значений, но это не оч удобно. / Что имеется под "модель с разным набором свойств" ?

Comment: если я правильно понял твое описание, я наверное тоже самое и имел ввиду. Ну можно еще сделать как варик подель под каждый тип "Свойства товара", и чтобы каждая эта модель ссылалась на "Свойства". Получится что ты сможешь создавать "Свойства товара" с любым типом, с нужными полями и при необходимости вытягивать все имеющиеся "Свойства товара", которые ссылаются на данное "Свойства"

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сделал "СвостваТовара" с полями "товар", "своство", "значение строка", "значение целое число", "значение вещ число", валидация через сигнал в clean модели. В результате в админке 1 поле для значения, и значения нужного типа попадают в нужные колонки.